# Dynamically changing/inserting the HTML and css for the login page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have one admin user and role is advisor. Now he has acess to his subdomain like `advisor_name.subdomain.com` which when hit shows the `login` window for the advisor.
Now at the profile setting page I need to permit him with two fileds one for inserting html code and another for css now on save these html and css must be stored into db table. The html css which he has inserted should be applied to the login page and should reflect over there.
How achieve this task any help ? How to apply the same html and css to the UI of login which he accessing?

Comment: These changes would affect the login page for all users right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored the two attributes as `html_code` and `css_code` in a table named `changes`, on your login page you can do it like this:

```
<% change = Change.first %>
<% if change.html_code.empty? %>
  # Normal login stuff
<% else %>
  <%= change.html_code %>
<% end %>

<% unless change.css_code.empty? %>
  <style type="text/css">
    <%= change.css_code %>
  </style>
<% end %>
```